# Что такое инфоблок в битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

В чем его суть, как хранятся данные и как они распределяются непосредственно в таблицах БД?

Answer (score 1):

[Информационные блоки (начальные сведения)](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&CHAPTER_ID=04477&LESSON_PATH=3905.4477).

Вкратце инфоблоки - это хранилище для информации в битриксе)

Comment: ну это-то понятно )) как они в базе хранятся? где-то видел схему, кажется из 4 таблиц, свойства отдельно и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Поля элементов хранятся в таблице b_Iblock_element, причем для всех инфоблоков, свойства - в зависимости от того какой включен режим хранения свойств в настройках инфоблока - либо также в одной таблице для всех инфоблоков, либо в отдельной для каждого (у каждого режима свои ограничения). В любом случае все таблицы модуля инфоблоков начинаются с b_iblock.

Примечание: работать в битриксе напрямую с базой данных - этого следует всегда избегать и делать это только в самом крайнем случае.